# Session to Query review using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I need to improve this working code fragment: (deprecated)

```
import org.hibernate.Query
```

..

```
public List<? extends PatientSuperClass> getPatients(){
        Session session=factory.getCurrentSession();   
        session.beginTransaction(); 
        Query<Patient> query =session.createQuery("select m from "+ Patient.class.getName() +" m");  
        List<Patient> patients= query.getResultList();   
        session.getTransaction().commit(); 
        return patients;
    }
```

that give me this situation: 
[image]

Comment: The javadoc of deprecated types or methods will usually point you in the right direction. Have you checked them?

Comment: To expand on what f1sh said: the JavaDoc on `org.hibernate.Query` (which I assume you are using) states: "**Deprecated.** (since 5.2). use 
 `org.hibernate.query.Query` instead". Now you just need to do that. From there you can probably resolve the other deprecation warning as well by having a look at the documentation (e.g. JavaDoc, user documentation etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to use a typed `Query<Patient>` you don't have to specify any type for `Query` and you can see from your screenshot that it's **deprecated**, it means that they provided an alternative method and this one may be removed on the future versions of the framework.

And I think you are confusing [**javax.persistence.Query**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Query.html) and [**org.hibernate.Query**](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html).

You need to use [**javax.persistence.Query**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Query.html) because it has a [getResultList()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#getResultList--) method which returns an **untyped** list as result.

> **List getResultList()**
>
> Execute a SELECT query and return the query results as an untyped List.

**Note:**

Note that [**org.hibernate.Query**](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html) no longer has a `getResultList()` method, that's why it's deprecated.

Comment: whot i used before: org.hibernate.Query

Comment: And it explains the problem.